# Apache + Django on Windows does not start

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to set up Apache with Django on Windows but it does not seem to work.

My settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

My wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from pathlib import Path

# Add project directory to the sys.path
path_home = str(Path(__file__).parents[1])
if path_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path_home)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mrt.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My httpd.conf

```
Listen 30080
Listen 8080


LoadFile "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python37.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/venv"
WSGIPythonPath "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/venv/Lib/site-packages"
```

My httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:30080>
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/logs/apache.error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/logs/apache.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/mrt/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/mrt">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/static"
    <Directory "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried to open http://localhost:30080/ but it says the website is not reachable.
I also have tried to change Ports to *8080 but without any effect, no error appears in logs, they are empty. Without Django config Apache works. Syntax is Ok.

Comment: Testing with: Win 10 + Apache 2.4.54 + Python 3.9.12 + Django 3.2.15 + mod_wsgi 4.9.4

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime kept trying new configurations. Ended up solving my problem after reading through some github issues. More specifically this one:

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/695#issuecomment-864748241

So, went ahead and re-installed Python and selected the 'Install for all users' flag.

Also, the `wsgi.py` file should be updated as shown in the OP question.

Updated the httpd.conf file to reflect this changes and this time the server worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to run a django app with apache on windows.

1. Use the below wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
import site
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# add python site packages, you can use virtualenvs also
site.addsitedir("C:/Program files/python39/Lib/site-packages")

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH 
sys.path.append('c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt') 
sys.path.append('c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/mrt')  

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mrt.settings' 
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mrt.settings")  
 
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

After run mod_wsgi-express module-config

this will output something like the below:

```
LoadFile "c:/Program Files/python/python39/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/Program Files/python39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/Program Files/python/python39"
```

Copy these lines and paste to end of conf\httpd.conf. Then open your configuration file for your vhost and write:

```
 ServerName localhost
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/logs/apache.error.log"
    CustomLog "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/logs/apache.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/mrt/wsgi.py"
    <Directory "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/mrt">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/static"
    <Directory "c:/users/user/pycharmprojects/djangoapi/mrt/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

2. I would recomend using [waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) as a good solution on running wsgi on Windows.
   All you have to do is to run

```
waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 yourapp.wsgi:application
and use ProxyPass http://localhost:8000 in your apache configuration
```

Let me know if it is ok.